# Promise returns undefined and data after

Tags: node.js, typescript, sqlite, es6-promise

For some reason I am getting undefined before the actual data using the following code

```
async findOne(query: string, parameters: string): Promise<T> {
    const stmt: sqlite3.Statement = await this.db.prepare(query)
    const info: T = stmt.get(parameters)
    this.db.close()

    return info
}

const user = await respository.findOne('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', targetUser.id)
console.log(user)
```

The console log outputs undefined and a object after that, what is the reason for this?

Comment: Did you forget node.js tag ?

Comment: with such little information, and so much of the code being `typescript`, the possibilities are numerous

Comment: I changed the tags

Comment: I think it console user before creating it so try ,to use try and catch

Answer (score 1):

Probably you will also need `await` here:

`const info: T = await stmt.get(parameters);`

From the documentation [here](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#statementgetparam--callback) it seems that `.get` is a classic callback function, so you will probably need to wrap it inside a Promise before using it with await.

Probably the same is true about `this.db.prepare(query)`? Checkout `util.promisify` from the standard node library if you don't want to do the promise wrapping yourself.

Also, you can't call an async function in open code. Try this:

```
(async () => {
   const user = await respository.findOne('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', targetUser.id)
})();
```

Hope this helps!